# Mention of Krishna Paksha Chaturdashi as Masik Shivratri Tithi in Hindu Shastras other than Skanda Purana?

Tags: shiva, puranas, fasting, panchang, shivaratri

Aside from one previous reference I found in the Skanda Purana ([What is the importance and concept behind Masik Shivratri?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29208/what-is-the-importance-and-concept-behind-masik-shivratri)) is there any additional reference to Masik (monthly) Shivratri in the Hindu Shastras as a day of fast and vigil (as opposed to the main one, Maha-Shivratri in the month of Magha)? I suppose I am just looking for some more excuse to fast on this day every month. Thank you for any help.